# Categories not editable from channel entry screen

Tags: categories, control-panel

I'm using ee v2.8.1 and when I try and click the red link next to 'edit categories' in the entry screen the link disappears and nothing happens? I can edit the categories if I go through the drop down under admin and then channel administration.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is a known bug. Patch and details: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20237